# How to 'read -s' in shell?

Tags: linux, bash, posix, sh, user-input

I know that user input can be read silently using bash with `read -s someVar` and I was wondering if there is a `/bin/sh` equivalent that allows user input without displaying it on the command line?

**Note:** I am just curious if `/bin/sh` `read` supports this feature somehow.

Comment: `bash` is *a* shell; are you asking if there is a solution that works in any POSIX-compliant shell?

Comment: With "shell" you mean the POSIX shell, aka `/bin/sh`?

Comment: Your question is weird, you seem to be confusing notions, "which is better bash or shell" doesn't make sense, since bash is a shell.

Comment: @AlexCohen: `/bin/sh`, as per the [POSIX specification of `read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html), supports neither `-s` nor `-p`.

Comment: @λuser I fixed the question to be more specific

Comment: @mklement0 Done and done :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `stty` command to turn off echoing of typed characters.

```
get_entry () {
  printf "Choose: "
  stty -echo
  IFS= read -r choice
  stty echo
  printf '\n'
}

get_entry

printf "You chose %s\n" "$choice"
```

Comment: This is a pretty great solution and it works in both `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash`

Comment: Why `IFS= `? Will that be reset to the default after the function call?

Comment: It ensures no leading or trailing whitespace will be stripped from the input. Along with the `-r` option, it means `choice` will be set to the exact keys entered by the user, with no unintentional splitting or expansion applied to the input. The value of `IFS` is local to the execution of `read`, and does not affect the value of `IFS` in the current shell.